# Fetching the virtually hosted site on apache from localhost

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have set up apache with 2 virtual hosts on a CentOS 6.4 box.
Virtual host 1 - abc.com.
Virtual host 2 - **def.com**.

And the default one is **abc.com**.

Now on the same box - I need to do **wget** on **def.com**.  But doing so will mean that I am accessing it via the outside network rather than using my localhost. How do I fetch def.com on this box without having to go through the outside network.

One way is to modify /etc/hosts. Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 wget --header="Host: def.com" http://127.0.0.1/
```

Basically, one needs to send the host header.

Comment: result = `Connecting to...` hanging forever

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

`wget http://Cent_OS_HOSTNAME/DEF_FOLDERDIRECTORY`

This will allow you to fetch them locally, in the internal network.

TO get your `Cent_OS_HOSTNAME` in terminal type in

`hostname -f` this will display your hostname.

Comment: what should I put for Cent_OS-HOSTNAME? I tried 127.0.0.1, but didn't work.